# Burnup/Burndown chart for Epic in Azure DevOps like JIRA Version Report

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking for a chart like Version Report in JIRA to track progress for an Epic. We're using Azure DevOps, and we have backlog structure 
Epic -> Feature -> User Stories.
Where User Stories are estimated, and every item has Area Path value.

Where in Azure DevOps can I find a chart like Version report (from JIRA) which show me also predicted completion date?

[Version Report example](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/version-report-777001521.html)

Comment: I am also looking for answer to this question. One way I could think of is to write your own burndown widget but that seems expensive effort.